# how to insert fixed value into table in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to insert a fixed date into table. How can I do this ?

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        Description :
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Description, new { @class = "textboxes" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        Date :
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date, new { @class = "textboxes" }) /// I wanna be here a fixed date .
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date)
    </div>
```

My controller code is:

```
public ActionResult Index(tblOrder tblorder)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.tblOrders.AddObject(tblorder);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.fxBudjet = new SelectList(db.tblBudjets, "ID", "Budjet", tblorder.fxBudjet);
            ViewBag.fxServiceType = new SelectList(db.tblServiceTypes, "ID", "Service", tblorder.fxServiceType);
            ViewBag.fxStartTime = new SelectList(db.tblStartDates, "ID", "StartDate", tblorder.fxStartTime);
            return View(tblorder);
        }
```

Do I need to change my controller code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inserting static date or text into database by asp.net MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10265925/inserting-static-date-or-text-into-database-by-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: not entirely sure what you mean, but if you mean you want to just display the value my answer should work

Comment: No I want to insert a date by my own code , not by user .. I don't want to show any date . just I want to register a date a data base by my own code .

Comment: also with your controller class you pasted you are redirecting to the same action you are in

Comment: @Manatherin : Yes I know .. I will change it . but I want to find a solution for this problem ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.Date, new { @class = "textboxes" })
```

if the date is needed in a post you can do

```
@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.Date, new { @class = "textboxes" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Date)
```

or in the post method you can use TryUpdateModel and exclude the date field

**Edit** from your update i would set the value for the model in the controller e.g. say you had a class year that you wanted to prepopulate the year value

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View(new Year() { Value = DateTime.Now.Year });
    }
```

again if you want it for the post you can use a hiddenfor or else regenerate it in the post

if this field is only required in the post method a better option might be to create a viewmodel without that field and then have some mapping logic in the post method

**Edit 2:** As with MVC music store you should really have 2 methods a get and a post. I will assume it is for a create.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.fxBudjet = new SelectList(db.tblBudjets, "ID", "Budjet");
    ViewBag.fxServiceType = new SelectList(db.tblServiceTypes, "ID", "Service");
    ViewBag.fxStartTime = new SelectList(db.tblStartDates, "ID", "StartDate");
    return View(new tblOrder() { Date = DateTime.Now });
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(tblOrder tblorder)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.tblOrders.AddObject(tblorder);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.fxBudjet = new SelectList(db.tblBudjets, "ID", "Budjet", tblorder.fxBudjet);
    ViewBag.fxServiceType = new SelectList(db.tblServiceTypes, "ID", "Service", tblorder.fxServiceType);
    ViewBag.fxStartTime = new SelectList(db.tblStartDates, "ID", "StartDate", tblorder.fxStartTime);
    return View(tblorder);
}
```

then in your view something like

```
@model tblOrder

@Html.BeginForm()
{
    @Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.Date, new { @class = "textboxes" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Date)
    ...other form stuff
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
}
```

Hopefully this should give you some idea of how to fix your code

Comment: I do this in Asp.net Webforms by this code : scm.parameters.addwithvalues("@Date",DateTime.Now); . How can I do this work in MVC .. I own want to insert date in form by my code .. not by user .

Comment: I don't need to show the date .. just I want to insert it .. I want to know when a user completed this form .. I want to know the date of registration .. just this .

Comment: Why don't you just set the date where you catch the form results? like `Model.Date = DateTime.Now`

Comment: I did this in view .. '<div class="editor-field">
            @{
    Model.RegDate = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
                }
        </div>' . but it shows this error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ..

Comment: @Persian. i don't mean in the view i mean in the controller where you capture the results

Comment: How can I add it in controller .. can you write for me a sample ?

Comment: @Persian. If you put your current controller code i'll try to give you a sample with it

Comment: @Persian. I would recommend that you do some MVC tutorials or read some articals like http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201104/Blog/ASP-NET-MVC-Post-Redirect-Get-Pattern/ as your controller code above is not really following mvc. Nerd Dinner http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/ and MVC music store http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/ are particularly good

Comment: I have Music store project .. but in this project I can't find any thing about my problem ..

Comment: I saw Music Store project .. it creates new album exactly like me .. do not have any idea ?!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10367/discussion-between-persian-and-manatherin)